# Trouble with location variables for creating zip

Tags: powershell, zip

I am writing a PS script to take a compressed folder in .axml, rename it to .zip, extract only certain files with "LMS" in the name, rename all "LMS" files dropping the first 9 chars. and then re-zipping only those files.
I'm running into an issue only at my zip command, as I need to use variables for location because the .axml is sequentially different each day.

My code is not perfect, I still have a lot of cleanup to do and have a lot of unused variables as I am trying to figure out how to get what I need. If I hard code the location the script executes flawlessly, but as I stated, the issue is that the zip archive will always be named differently. I suppose after I rename the files I could copy them all to a folder that's pre-named and then zip that?

Anyway, my code is below, and any insight as to how I can do this with variables would be greatly appreciated. If you'd like to run it yourself, you just need a zip archive with a few files in it (name them something 9 chars. and then lms at least, and they need to be .pdf) and it should work :-)

Zip folder command:

```
#Re-zip only files with LMSxxx.pdf
$source = $UnzippedFolder
$destination =  $RootPath + "\upload.zip"
If(Test-path $destination) {Remove-Item $destination}
Add-Type -AssemblyName "system.io.compression.filesystem"
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)
```

Error with this:

```
Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find
a part of the path 'C:\Users\USER\FOLDER\SOURCE'."
At C:\Users\USER\FOLDER\SCRIPT.ps1:105 char:1
+ [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotFoundException`
```

Full code can be found here:
https://goo.gl/x6Gx0Z

Comment: The error message says your source folder doesn't exist.

Comment: If you're using Powershell 5.0, you could use the archive cmdlets https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn841357.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Nick,

I am assuming that you sanitized the error output and the issue is that you are passing a string with a space in it such as "C:\Users\Nick Corsentino..".

The fix is to pass the old 8.3 path format.  I leverage a function I found below (my apologies for not being able to attribute the source, but don't recall where I found it).

```
function Get-ShortPathName ($DirPath) {

$fso = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject

Get-Item -path $DirPath | ForEach-Object{

    if($_.PSIsContainer) {
        return $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).ShortPath
        }
    else {
        return $fso.GetFile($_.FullName).ShortPath
        }
    }
}
```

Then just call it...

```
$source = Get-ShortPathName $source
```

This process fixed my problem.

For others looking at your code, you preface the $destination with a path and not just a file name.  This is critical or the invocation of -

```
[io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($source, $destination)
```

will put the file into the "C:\Users\Nick Corsentino" directory and not put it into the current (script execution) directory.